# @ViewChildren Querylist Array is empty when children are rendered with *ngFor

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent'
    styleUrls: [],
    templateUrl: `<div>
                    <app-child *ngFor="let data of datas" [data]="data"></app-
                    child>
                  <div>'

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children;
```

Hello, as above I have several `<app-child>` components in Parent component rendered with ngFor. I'd like to access each child component's methods within the parent component. However, the Querylist keep returning an empty array.

Note that both parent and child components have been declared within the seperate root component's app-module. The child components renders no problem when parent's "datas" field is filled/changed. The problem is I just can't capture the rendered Child components in @ViewChildren decorator property.

Edit: Here's the console log:

```
QueryList {dirty: false, _results: Array(0), changes: EventEmitter}changes: 
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, 
isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}dirty: falsefirst: (...)last: 
(...)length: (...)_results: (4) [AnswerButtonComponent, 
AnswerButtonComponent, AnswerButtonComponent, 
AnswerButtonComponent]__proto__: Object
```

There seems to be two _results attribute in the query list, the first is empty second has 4 references to the child components.

How do I extract those?

Comment: You are not importing `ChildComponent` in parent. `ChildComponent` is not a part of `@angular/core` module

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, it's just a mistake I made here, I have it imported from the right directory in my file.

I'll edit it here

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you're using a custom directive (such as `ChildComponent` here) don't forget to import it into your `ngModule` too or everything will silently fail. That will result in the length of the ViewChildren always being 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the changes of the ViewChildren as @kshatriiya mentioned.

Initialization of the viewChildren has to go inside ngAfterViewInit and wait for a next javascript event cycle to initialize.

```
Please find working prototype here - https://plnkr.co/edit/fBR3CtJ4wYfcPnIISVPW?p=preview
```

If you need more insight on the usage of **ViewChild, ViewChildren, ContentChild, ContentChildren** read this [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20190815162546/https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e) Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Nvm, I figured it out, the QueryList has changes property that you can subscribe to. My guess is when NgFor renders the components, the subscribe method returns the components.

```
this.children.changes.subscribe(c => { c.toArray().forEach(item => { 
console.log(item);}) });
```